# When the value is not found no message is shown

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following example database:

```
rfidtags` (`name`, `id`, `gender`, `email`, `mobile`) VALUES
('Alsan', '39EAB06D', 'Male', 'mydigitalnepal@gmail.com', '9800998787'),
('John', '769174F8', 'Male', 'john@email.com', '23456789'),
('Thvhm,b', '81A3DC79', 'Female', 'jgkhkkmanjil@gmail.com', '45768767564'),
```

And the following code:

```
<?php
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_port = '';
$mysql_user = 'user';
$mysql_pass = 'password';
$mysql_mydb = 'rfidcards';

$con = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_mydb );
if ($con -> connect_errno) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $con -> connect_error;
exit(2);
}

//$tagid = '39EAB06D'; 
$tagid = 'CCCCCCCC'; 

$query = "SELECT name, id  FROM rfidtags WHERE id = '$tagid'";

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $id);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // debug init
    //var_dump($stmt);
    // debug end


    echo "$name $id\n";

    $stmt->close();

} else {

echo "failed to fetch data\n";
}

$con->close();
```

Tags
tagid = '39EAB06D'
and
tagid = 'CCCCCCCC'
are for testing purposes.

When the first is selected, the ressult is shown, but when the second (non existant on the database) is selected, a blank line is shown, instead of "failed to fetch data"

Comment: That's because `prepare` will not fail if no record is found. you should be checking the result of the query ($name, $id, or number of results found, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo "failed to fetch data\n";` is in the wrong place. `$con->prepare($query)` will only return false if there was something wrong in preparing the statement not if the statement returned no entries.

You would want to do the if check on your fetch like:

```
if($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "$name $id\n";
} else {
    echo "No result returned";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli::prepare()` does not fail when the query returns zero records. In fact, it's a rather bad practice to check if `prepare` succeeded or not.

Your code would be much easier if you used PDO instead of mysqli, but if you are willing to suffer with mysqli then the right code to do this kind of thing would be:

```
<?php

$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_port = '';
$mysql_user = 'user';
$mysql_pass = 'password';
$mysql_mydb = 'rfidcards';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_mydb);
$con->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

//$tagid = '39EAB06D';
$tagid = 'CCCCCCCC';

$query = "SELECT name, id  FROM rfidtags WHERE id = ?";

$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $tagid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($name, $id);
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "$name $id\n";
} else {
    echo "failed to fetch data\n";
}
```

Comment: "Your code would be much easier if you used PDO instead of mysqli" what is PDO? can you point the way?

Comment: @PauloWollny If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong because mysqli::prepare() return  mysqli_stmt or false.
Generaly, it return false only when you have a wrong SQL query.
But in your case, you have a correct SQL query even if the id you request does not exist in the table.
So you need to check the results after executing stmt but not the stmt before executing.

Comment: thx. Dharman and Zachary helped to solve,